# PHP namespaces , Uncaught Error: Class X not found in C:\Y.php

Tags: php, namespaces

I'am new with php and try to make a little demo API wich i can use for test purposals.... and i learn a little bit from PHP :-D

So... my situation:

I try to get some data from a mysql db and encode it to json for the API. Getting data from the database works and i can encode it to json. Now my project contains more and more files so i decided to "clean" my project by sort php files in folders and using namespaces. (i know how to work with namespaces from C#)

my problem:

I get this error `<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'DemoApi\api\AlertManager' not found in C:\Users\XXX\MyProject\api\Alerts.php:44` (or simular) as answer on many requests (localhost/api/xxx.php) *(on this line: $alertManager = new AlertManager();)*

Iam 100% sure the class AlertManager is located in the namespace DemoApi\api\ so this can't be the problem.

my code:

```
//AlertManager.php
<?php namespace DemoApi\DataManagers;
    class AlertManager{
    public function getAllAlerts()
    {
        //Gets all alerts from the DB
    }
    }

//Alerts.php
<?php namespace DemoApi\api;
    use DemoApi\DataManagers\AlertManager;
    //And i tryed: use DemoApi\DataManagers;

    $alertManager = new AlertManager();
    $alerts = $alertManager->getAllAlerts();
    echo json_encode($alerts);

//composer.json (whatever this is or does, but find on the internet i needed to add the psr-4....)
//and did "composer dumpautoload"
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": "src/"},
    "psr-4": {
      "DemoApi\\": "\\"
    }
  }
}
```

i call the class alerts.php, Can someone explain me where it goes wrong... and why because in my logic everything is correct???

Comment: Did you re-generate the autoloader after editing your composer.json file? If not, run `composer dumpautoload`.

Comment: Yes i did , i update it in my question

Comment: A colleague of me told me that it is something with the PSR but he doesn't know what exacly the problem is, maybe this information is usefull to someone who tries to help me.

Comment: I think iám a litle bit further then yesterday. The file files are sorted in directories (simular to the namespaces, where DemoApi is the root of the project) When i set all the php files in the root of the project the namespaces work fine but when i move the files back into directories the whole thing is messed up again. I thought i can use namespaces instead include "folder\subfolder\file.php" but not? .... and i need to use allways a include?

Comment: Weird, i got it working 100% in a new project but in my current project it wont work and i still get the "can not found" error. When i create a new project and copy over the functions from the classes it break up again ??? :-S

Comment: Iam not 100% sure about it, but i think the problem occurs becouse i program on windows (wamp) but the application runs on linux. The linux / and \ are different from windows so this can be the problem. I post this not because i found a solution (made a demo API in .net which worked fine for me) but only to try help people with the same problem to find a solution.